# Get first week day of specific year-month

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

How can I get the date of for example 'first wednesday of april 2013' using c# .net 2.0 ?

is there any helper methods for this kind of job in .net or should I write my own helper method? If there is no method for this kind of job please help me out for writing my own method.

```
DateTime GetFirstXDayFromY(string dayName, DateTime targetYearMonth)
{
    ///???
}
```

Comment: Well get the first day of the month, increment day by 1 and stop when you find match for `DayOfWeek`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of answers of @vc and @Jayesh I've come up with this method. Thanks a lot.

```
public static DateTime GetFirstDay(int year, int month, DayOfWeek day, int occurance)
{
    DateTime result = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    int i = 0;

    while (result.DayOfWeek != day || occurance != i)
    {
        result = result.AddDays(1);
        if((result.DayOfWeek == day))
            i++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This code did not work for me when asking for 5th dayofweek of month. Every month except February leap year has at least one dayofweek that occurs 5 times.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static DateTime GetFirstDay(int year, int month, DayOfWeek day)
{
    DateTime result = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    while (result.DayOfWeek != day)
    {
        result = result.AddDays(1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

If you were on .net >= 3.5 you could use Linq:

```
public static DateTime GetFirstDay(int year, int month, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 7).
                      Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day)).
                      First(dateTime => (dateTime.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
    // Get the Nth day of the month
    private static DateTime NthOf(DateTime CurDate, int Occurrence, DayOfWeek Day)
    {
        var fday = new DateTime(CurDate.Year, CurDate.Month, 1);

        if (Occurrence == 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                if (fday.DayOfWeek == Day)
                {
                    return fday;
                }
                else
                {
                    fday = fday.AddDays(1);
                }
            }

            return fday;
        }
        else
        {

            var fOc = fday.DayOfWeek == Day ? fday : fday.AddDays(Day - fday.DayOfWeek);

            if (fOc.Month < CurDate.Month) Occurrence = Occurrence + 1;
            return fOc.AddDays(7 * (Occurrence - 1));
        }
    }
```

How to call/use them?

```
NthOf(targetYearMonth, 1, DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
```

Comment: Your code worked for me. Thank you very much. It works flawlessly on "5th" weekday of month.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework makes it easy to determine the ordinal day of the week for a particular date, and to display the localized weekday name for a particular date.

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762911.aspx

Comment: Wondering how does this help in getting *'first wednesday of april 2013'*

Comment: it has all information and implementation to write your own code to do the task